# Node JS synchronous events

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am writing a node js program to read content from a file , I am executing this program multiple times in a short time. Sometimes I can see file content and sometimes I do not (PFA screenshot) , can anyone please explain why this is happening ? Is this because I am not using promises ?

```
var fs= require('fs');
fs.readFile('myData.json', (err, data) => {
  if(err)
    console.log('Error Found',err.code);
  else {
    console.log('inside else');
    fs.open('myData.json', 'wx', (err, fd) => {
      console.log('inside open file');
      fs.writeFile('myData.json','test data',(err)=>{
        if(err) console.log('error writing data');
      });
      fs.readFile('myData.json','utf8',(err, data) => {
        console.log('read file'+data);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Screen Shot :

[image]

Comment: I don't see that you're closing the file after reading/writing. I believe it's good practice to make sure the file is closed before moving on and maybe that's why it fails inconsistently.

Comment: You start to read, wait for that, start to open, wait for that, then write and read at the same time. Maybe some cleaner indentation would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try after fixing following code

```
fs.writeFile('myData.json','test data',(err)=>{
  if(err) console.log('error writing data');
  fs.readFile('myData.json','utf8',(err, data) => {
    console.log('read file'+data);
  });
});
```

You have placed read file in async with write file. You need to read file after writing it.

Answer (score 2):

`fs.readFile` and `fs.writeFile` are asynchronous. You start the readFile immediately after calling writeFile. This means writeFile may or may not (probably not) have time to finish before readFile executes.

Try putting the readFile within the writeFile callback. The callback is called after the asynchronous function completes, so it allows you to handle code in a synchronous manner.

I'm not sure the readFile -> open -> writeFile -> readFile logic makes a lot of sense, though.

Comment: You are right ,  readFile -> open -> writeFile -> readFile  makes no sense .
I am new to Async programming and Node JS was trying something very random , thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2):

Using latest [Node.js v9.2.0 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)

> `fs.writeFile(file, data[, options], callback)`
>
> ...
>
> Asynchronously writes data to a file, replacing the file if it already
>   exists. data can be a string or a buffer.

Since you wanna writeFile synchronous you should use

> `fs.writeFileSync(file, data[, options])`
>
> ...
>
> The synchronous version of `fs.writeFile()`. Returns undefined.